# Dealing with slower consumer trying to consume data from faster producers

Tags: rtos

- There's a producer thread `t1` that's reading and outputting sensor `S1` data at 20Hz.
- There's another producer thread `t2` that's reading and outputting a sensor `S2` data at 25Hz-
- There's a consumer thread `t3` that's consuming the data from both `t1` and `t2` at 18Hz.

What should be the approach(es) for `t3` to be reading the data from each thread correctly given its less frequency rate?

One naïve approach that I thought of was consuming 18 samples/second from `t1` and `t2` but then it's scrapping 2 samples from `S1` and 5 from `S2`.

A rough idea. Also, how would a consumer filter out reading from `S1` and `S2`?

```c
void t1()
{
    const TickType_t xDelay = 50;   // 20Hz
    
    while(true)
    {
        uint8_t val = readSensorS1();
        
        lock();
        pushToFifo(val);
        unlock();
        
        vTaskDelay(xDelay);
    }
}

void t2()
{
    const TickType_t xDelay = 40;   // 25Hz
    
    while(true)
    {
        uint8_t val = readSensorS2();
        
        lock();
        pushToFifo(val);
        unlock();
        
        vTaskDelay(xDelay);
    }
}

void t3()
{
    const TickType_t xDelay = 55;   // 18Hz
    
    while(true)
    {
        lock();
        uint8_t val = readFromFifo();
        unlock();
        
        vTaskDelay(xDelay);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

> outputting sensor S1 data at 20Hz

20Hz is how fast the thread `t1` runs. So every 1/20s, it wakes up, reads sensor data, and puts the data into the FIFO. So in a second time, FIFO shall contain 20 samples of `S1`.

> If it's a continuously varying quantity, does it vary so fast that 20 measurements per second are needed in order to get an accurate picture of what's going on?

Somewhat yes. We don't want to be discarding or losing much of the samples otherwise that'd lead to a noisy signal

> What does "consuming the data from both t1 and t2 at 18Hz" mean?

The consumer thread wakes up at 1/18s, and reads the `S1`, `S2` samples from the FIFO, which gets processed by something else (not mentioned here).

> Is the consumer able to read multiple data points from each producer in a single cycle?

Yes. As evident from my example in the description

*"One naïve approach that I thought of was consuming 18 samples/second from t1 and t2 but then it's scrapping 2 samples from S1 and 5 from S2."*

Comment: Could you change these rates or are they strongly constrained?

Comment: Also, what sort of processing are you doing afterwards? Is it important that the data remains synchronised and free from artefacts?

Comment: it's an open-ended problem for now. let's take both the cases where we could change the rates and we couldn't. I reckon in the former, would you make consumer slower, say, 1Hz which means every second a consumer wakes up, reads 25+20 samples?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in this question for us to be able to provide meaningful advice. It's obvious that either the producers have to produce fewer than 45 data points per second, or the consumer has to consume more than 18 data points per second, or the consumer has to consume fewer data points than the producers produce. The choice between these three options depends on information that you haven't given us.

Comment: In particular, what does "outputting sensor S1 data at 20Hz" mean? Does it mean that one sensor reading is taken and output once every 1/20 s? Does it mean that the producer sends one message every 1/20 s, but you can choose what information is in the message? What is the nature of the quantity that's being measured? Is it a continuously varying quantity that we're choosing to measure 20 times per second? Are 20 different objects passing by each second and each one measured only once?

Comment: If it's a continuously varying quantity, does it vary so fast that 20 measurements per second are needed in order to get an accurate picture of what's going on? What does "consuming the data from both t1 and t2 at 18Hz" mean? Does it mean that every 1/18 s, the consumer consumes one data point from t1 and one data point from t2? Does it mean that every 1/18 s, the consumer does _something_, but you can choose what it does? Is the consumer able to read multiple data points from each producer in a single cycle?

Comment: Is it possible to put any kind of processor in between the producers and the consumer? If some of the data points are dropped, will the remaining data still be usable? If consecutive data points are combined by averaging them together, will the resulting data still be usable? Is it possible to slow the producers down? Is it possible to speed the consumer up? These are the kinds of things someone would have to know in order to know what to do.

Comment: I tried to answer most of your questions in the recent edit

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is more of an algorithm question than EE, but let it be.

I will assume that frequencies are fixed. Therefore, between each two t3 ticks, both t1 and t2 tick either once (most of the time) or twice (one right after t3 tick number N and one just before the next t3 tick N+1).

So you can fundamentally choose one of the two paths:

1. Use only the freshest sample (t1/t2 values). If two t1 ticks happened before t3 tick, you use only the latest and discard the first one. It's been overwritten. It's the simplest way, and, depending on your goal, can be good enough.
2. You create a data structure that will hold two latest samples of t1/t2 and a flag for each which will state which one of them was read/written in t3, so that when two t1 values arrive, t3 knows it needs to process not one but two values this time.

Obviously, if you can change frequencies, then nothing stops you from getting value of t1, followed by t2, and then you immediately run t3 to process it all (t1 and t2 executed in parallel or sequentially, followed by t3 processing their data)

Comment: shouldn't there be at most one `t2` (50ms) and `t1` (40ms) ticks between two `t3`  (55ms) ticks? assuming that, `t3` every 55ms of waking up consumes each sample from both `t1` and `t2`

Comment: If t2/t1 are smaller, there always will be that one situation where there are two t1/t2 between every t3. Like 90% of the time (or more, calculable) there will be one, but there will be one time out of many when t1 occurs just after t3 and again right before the next t3

Answer (score 0):

Reading data for full BW requires 2f sampling rate otherwise there is aliasing.  even so this only gives a SNR of 1 at f data rate with 2f sample rate. So the resolution or SNR or dynamic range resolution of sampled data or "consumer thread" determines what filtering you need to average the result to the required resolution and result in attenuation of aliasing noise of f signal and f3 sampling rate.

If the signal is just binary data such as from a PWM to measure duty cycle, then you can sample at the same rate synchronously or sub-sample with uncertainty in the average result of successive samples to get duty cycle.  I have used the sync. @ same sample rate in past designs to accurately send motor current using a <~ 1kHz PWM with a sub-channel 12Mbps data stream and 1kHz sub-frame rate of a spare bit with zero aliasing. A sync'd register sends the binary bit phase 1,0 without aliasing .

You must learn Shannon's Law and Aliasing effects.